# Grab certain values from dataframe column and making new dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A column in my `DataFrame` is labeled as `Occupation`. In that column, `Real Estate` is represented in several different ways. These are the three ways it's represented:

```
RealEstate
REALESTATE
RealEstateDeveloper
Other occupations I don't want
```

I want to pull every iteration and variation of `Real Estate` and put it into it's own `DataFrame`. This is what I have:

```
dfRealEstate = df[(df.Occupation == 'RealEstate') | (df.Occupation == 'REALESTATE') | (df.Occupation == 'RealEstateDeveloper')]
```

I get a blank `dataframe`. My output should look like this:

```
col1

RealEstate
RealEstate
REALESTATE
REALESTATE
REALESTATE
REALESTATE
RealEstateDeveloper
RealEstateDeveloper
RealEstateDeveloper
```

Comment: `df.Occupation.str.lower().str.contains('realestate')`.

Comment: I get an array of booleans that are all `false` when I try that

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your rows before:

```
df['Occupation'].str.strip().str.casefold().str.contains('realestate')
```

Comment: Wouldn't `str.contains('realestate', case=False)` be more efficient than `casefold()` + `contains()` ?

Comment: You have probably right. I'm trying to make it work for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a mask from a list of variations:

```
mask_realEstate = df.loc[:,"Occupation"].isin(['RealEstate','REALESTATE','RealEstateDeveloper'])
```

Now, use to mask with `.loc` to create a new DataFrame:

```
dfRealEstate = df.loc[mask_realEstate,"Occupation"]
```